# Python Scrapy Selector Issue

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to parse advert information from a website called donedeal.ie. Direct [link](http://www.donedeal.ie/find/all/for-sale/Ireland/?sort=AGE%20DESC&source=ALL&start=0) to the page in question.

I am receiving  ERROR: **Spider error processing http://www.donedeal.ie/find/all/for-sale/ireland>**

Specifics of error:  exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: //div[@class="listing-info"]/

If I text the xpath out in the console of chrome it works perfectly, and the exact information I want parses and displays within the console.

Anyone who could shed some light on this, would be greatly appreciated. I have tried the same code for other sites and xpath's and they seems to work.

I have included the full trace, and code below.

```html
2015-03-24 18:47:06+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.5 started (bot: stack)
2015-03-24 18:47:06+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-03-24 18:47:06+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'stack.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['stack.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'stack'}
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/__init__.py:21: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: ITEM_PIPELINES defined as a list or a set is deprecated, switch to a dict
  category=ScrapyDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=1)
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Connected to MongoDB mongodb://localhost:27017, using "donedeal/adverts"
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: MongoDBPipeline
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [stack] INFO: Spider opened
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [stack] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [stack] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.donedeal.ie/find/all/for-sale/Ireland/?sort=AGE+DESC&source=ALL&start=0> (referer: None)
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [stack] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://www.donedeal.ie/find/all/for-sale/Ireland/?sort=AGE+DESC&source=ALL&start=0>
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
            call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 638, in _tick
            taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 484, in _oneWorkUnit
            result = next(self._iterator)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
            work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
            yield next(it)
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py", line 26, in process_spider_output
            for x in result:
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
            return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/urllength.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
            return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
            return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
          File "/home/fiosta/donedeal/stack/stack/spiders/stack-spider.py", line 15, in parse
            adverts = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="listing-info"]/')
          File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 98, in xpath
            raise ValueError("Invalid XPath: %s" % query)
        exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath: //div[@class="listing-info"]/

2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [stack] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [stack] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 273,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 19348,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 24, 18, 47, 7, 664722),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
         'log_count/ERROR': 1,
         'log_count/INFO': 8,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'spider_exceptions/ValueError': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 24, 18, 47, 7, 122714)}
2015-03-24 18:47:07+0000 [stack] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Spider file (stack-spider.py)

```js
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.selector import Selector

from stack.items import StackItem


class StackSpider(Spider):
    name = "stack"
    allowed_domains = ["donedeal.ie"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.donedeal.ie/find/all/for-sale/Ireland/?sort=AGE+DESC&source=ALL&start=0",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        adverts = Selector(response).xpath('//div[@class="listing-info"]')

        for advert in adverts:
            item = StackItem()
            item['title'] = advert.xpath(
                'span[@class="county"]/text()').extract()[0]
            item['url'] = advert.xpath(
                'span[@class="multiline-tickets"]/text()').extract()[0]
            yield item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong slashes in selector. Try

```
xpath('//div[@class="listing-info"]')
```

Also when messing around with this stuff, scrapy shell is useful.

```
scrapy shell 'http://www.donedeal.ie/find/all/for-sale/Ireland/?sort=AGE+DESC&source=ALL&start=0'
```

Comment: Apologises, had spotted that but didn't update in post. Still getting the same error. Getting a successful 200 response when using scrapy shell.

Comment: In your output you still have an extra trailing slash. Every character is important.

Comment: It was down to the url item list being null, but you were correct in highlighting it was down to xpath.